# Check if Spree Cart is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

How can I check if the Spree cart is empty, so I can change the button if it isn't?

I thought there was a method `line_items.count`...

```
 <% unless line_items.count > 0 %>
        <%= link_to "<button>Empezar Pedido</button>".html_safe, "/shop" %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to "<button>Terminar Pedido</button>".html_safe, "/shop" %>
    <% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple I solved my this problem like this

In application_controller.rb

```
def load_cart
 @order = current_order
end
```

In frontend in you case

```
 <% unless @order.line_items.count > 0 %>
    <%= link_to "<button>Empezar Pedido</button>".html_safe, "/shop" %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "<button>Terminar Pedido</button>".html_safe, "/shop" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: Qubaish, after refreshing the page, my cart popup goes empty on production. The "perform_caching" is enabled - config.action_controller.perform_caching = true. When I go to checkout page, i can see those items. My spree version is 3.1.0. I spent 2 day but didn't find the solution. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think "perform_caching" is irrelevant. Now there are two scenario 1) If your popup is using ajax request then please see response either your request is getting line items or not ? 2)  if you are not using ajax req you can load line items as mentioned in my above answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Qubaish. I did changes as per you mentioned. But 1) I removed all items form the cart and refreshing the page, all removed line items are displaying in the popup again instead of empty popup. 2) Another scenario is there are two items in the popup, then remove both these items and add new item. When popup opens, both these items are added in the popup. Actual behaviour should be add only one item. It's really strange that without adding the items, it populating in the cart. Let me know if you have any solution. Thanks.

Comment: yeah it strange, but for that you have to debug your code
1) Disable cache
2) when you remove item from your cart, please do check your  database and ensure that either your item remove from database or not.
3) Or just play in rails console and create manullay line items and then delete line items from your console and check behaviour.